# How to compare a list element with the next element, to yield this element?

Tags: scala

As I noted in the title, how to compare the element of index N with element of index N+1, if elements compared are exactly the same, yield element only once.
I know I can use toSet, to get a set of unique elements, but this does not help me because, my list can contain duplicated elements but duplicated element can't be the next element in my list.

```
val ll = List(1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3)
// Desired output: List(1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 5, 6, 3)
```

I got a "near working solution" using zipWithIndex.collect, but when I compare inside it, index runs OutOfBounds. I can make this to work if I can use two conditions inside, first check maximum index to be index = (list.size-1) then I can compare list(index) != list(index+1) then yield list(index)

What I have tried without success (because of OutOfBounds), is:

```
times.zipWithIndex.collect
{
    case (element, index)
        // index+1 will be incremented out of my list
        if (times(index) != times(index+1)) => times(index)
}
```

This can work if I can use one more condition to limit index, but does not work with two conditions:

```
times.zipWithIndex.collect
{
    case (element, index)
        if (index < times.size)
            if (times(index) != times(index+1)) => times(index)
}
```

I appreciate any kind of alternative.

Comment: I've always been puzzled why Scala's collections library doesn't have this sort of grouping function. In Haskell you could just write this as `map head $ group ll`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin You mean `map head $ group ll` is the complete code and would give the desired output? I'm curious...

Comment: @bjfletcher Yeah :) The heavily lifting is done by `group`, which turns `[1,2,3,6,3,7,5,5,6,3]` into `[[1],[2],[3],[6],[3],[7],[5,5],[6],[3]]`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Nice, very nice indeed. Just asked a question about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125654/scala-equivalent-of-haskells-group-for-data-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip the list with itself, dropping the first element so that you compare elements at index N with N + 1. You only need to append the last element (you may want to use a `ListBuffer` as appending the last element requires to copy the list).

```
val r = times.zip(times.drop(1)).withFilter(t => t._1 != t._2).map(_._1) :+ times.last
```

---

```
scala> val times = List(1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3)
times: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3)

scala> val r = times.zip(times.drop(1)).withFilter(t => t._1 != t._2).map(_._1) :+ times.last
r: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 5, 6, 3)
```

Comment: This will output a "freak" result as:
Vector(L, i, s, t, :,  , L, i, s, t, (, 1, ,,  , 2, ,,  , 3, ,,  , 6, ,,  , 3, ,,  , 7, ,,  , 5, ,,  , 6, ), 3; Size: 10)

Comment: @LXSoft I've tested it on your input and I got the expected output.

Comment: val L : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3)


println("List: " + L.zip(L.drop(1)).withFilter(t => t._1 != t._2).map(_._1) :+ L.last+"; Size: " + L.zip(times.drop(1)).withFilter(t => t._1 != t._2).map(_._1).size)

Result is as in first comment.

Comment: @LXSoft Because there is string concatenation involved. Add parenthesis around the first expression:     `println("List: " + (L.zip(L.drop(1)).withFilter(t => t._1 != t._2).map(_._1) :+ L.last)+"; Size: " + L.zip(L.drop(1)).withFilter(t => t._1 != t._2).map(_._1).size)`

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
ll.foldLeft(List[Int]())((acc, x) => acc match {case Nil => List(x) case y => if (y.last == x) y else y :+ x})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my alternative using the sliding function:

```
val ll = List(1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3)
ll.sliding(2)
    .filter( t => t.length > 1 && t(0) != t(1) )
    .map( t => t(0) )
    .toList :+ ll.last
```